# With XML::Twig, is there a way of find a 'first_child' with a particular attribute?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I've some XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet>
<Category>
   <Name mode="source">somename</Name>
   <Name mode="destination">someothername</Name>
   <Content>Some text here</Content>
</Category>
</DataSet>
```

What I'm trying to do is process the 'Category', and extract a different name based on the context.

I've tried iterating it with `children` - this works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub process_category {
    my ( $twig, $category ) = @_;
    my $cat_name;
    foreach my $name ( $category->children('Name') ) {
        if ( $name->att('mode') eq 'source' ) {
            $cat_name = $name->text;
        }
    }

    print "$cat_name ", $category->first_child_text('Content'), "\n";
}

my $twig =
    XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'Category' => \&process_category } )
    ->parse( \*DATA );


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet>
<Category>
   <Name mode="source">somename</Name>
   <Name mode="destination">someothername</Name>
   <Content>Some Text</Content>
</Category>
</DataSet>
```

However I'm wondering - is there a better way than iterating the elements? I can't figure out if `first_child` supports an attribute search, or if there's another method that does the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use XML::Twig's `get_xpath` method to search for matching values in attributes. For example:

```
my $cat_name = $category->get_xpath('./Name[@mode="source"]', 0)->text;
```

By default, get_xpath returns an array. By passing the "0", only the first element of the array is passed (which is what you need and likely there will be only one match anyway). Then, the text is pulled out with `->text`. Use that and you can delete your for loop.

Comment: Lovely, that sounds even better than the code ref solution I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a code_ref to `first_child`. This sub is handed each element in turn, and if it returns 'true' then the `first_child` method matches. (And then doesn't continue looking).

So this should do the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub is_name_source {
    my ($element) = @_;

    print $element ->tag, "\n";
    if (    $element->tag eq 'Name'
        and $element->att('mode') eq 'source' )
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

sub process_category {
    my ( $twig, $category ) = @_;
    my $cat_name = $category->first_child( \&is_name_source )->text;
    print "$cat_name ", $category->first_child_text('Content'), "\n";
}

my $twig =
    XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'Category' => \&process_category } )
    ->parse( \*DATA );


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet>
<Category>
   <Name mode="source">somename</Name>
   <Name mode="destination">someothername</Name>
   <Content>Some Text</Content>
</Category>
</DataSet>
```

You could of course, inline `is_name_source` with an anonymous sub. That's a matter of taste.